# Implemented LINE login with OIDC provider in firebase auth, struggling to register email on LINE

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, line

I implemented a login flow for LINE using the OIDC provider in firebase auth, but I am having trouble registering my email address on LINE to firebase auth.

## Details

The authentication flow for LINE is as follows:
https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/line-login/integrate-line-login/

The method for login is as follows:

```js
export const signInWithLine = async () => {
  const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.line');
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    bot_prompt: 'aggressive',.
    initial_amr_display: 'lineqr', }
  });
  return await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
}
```

Login system cannot obtain an email address from a user without applying for email on LINE Developer site, so I applied for one.

I have confirmed that I can get the email by decoding 'oauthIdToken' of 'userCredential' in the output of 'signInWithPopup'.

However, for some reason, the email in the output of 'signInWithPopup' and the email in the 'providerData' did not include LINE email, and it could not be linked to an existing user with the same email.(※I can get uid, displayName and photoURL.)

Upon investigation, I found that LINE's `GET https://api.line.me/oauth2/v2.1/userinfo` endpoint for retrieving user information did not include the email in the response.
(API reference: https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/line-login/#userinfo)

So, my hypothesis is that firebase auth is not decoding the idToken to get the email and other user information, but is getting the user information from requesting /userinfo, which is why it is not getting the email.

Does anyone know how to implement LINE login including email?

## Supplement

- I set auth setting to "Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address"
- I try provider.addScope('email') but nothing changed.